# CCS Menu Changing from Homepage

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

If you look at the website below, you can see my issue.

On the Homepage, the top menu works as intended.

On any either page, the menu items are semi-transparent when hovered over and they disappear! Also when you scroll down, the entire menu is transparent as well. I've been fighting with this for hours.

Comment: Please, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your theme's Custom CSS:

```
.inner-main-title:before {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

EDIT: Also add this CSS:

```
.navbar {
    z-index: 9 !important;
}
```

Comment: I edited my reply. It should work on scroll now too.